# Segmentation fault(core dumped) in C after running

Tags: c

I am a beginner to C language and I wrote this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int day = 35;
 if (day>31)
   printf('Please enter a valid date');
  else if (day%7==1)
   printf('Monday');
  else if (day%7==2)
   printf('Tuesday');
  else if (day%7==3)
   printf('Wednesday');
  else if (day%7==4)
   printf('Thursday');
  else if (day%7==5)
   printf('Friday');
  else if (day%7==6)
   printf('Saturday');
  else
   printf('Sunday');
  return 0;
}
```

I ran this code on Replit and it is showing Segmentation error(core dumped).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62ibu.png)
Plz help me to solve this problem and explain about my mistake

I tried the above code on replit and I expected to get my result as-Please enter a valid date
But I got segmentation error(core dumped)

Comment: C strings are surrounded by `"`, not `'`.

Comment: You must use *double quotes* (`"`) around strings.  The single quote is for a single literal character.

Comment: Replit should have given plenty of warnings and other diagnostics - always pay attention to them.

Comment: Thanks everyone but can anyone tell me what connection it has with segmentation error?

Answer (score 2):

`''` are character literals; `""` are string literals. You cannot have a multi-length character literal. [Here](https://onlinegdb.com/W0IJ2eLb3) is working code:

```c
int day = 35;
if (day > 31)
  printf("Please enter a valid date");
else if (day % 7 == 1)
  printf("Monday");
else if (day % 7 == 2)
  printf("Tuesday");
else if (day % 7 == 3)
  printf("Wednesday");
else if (day % 7 == 4)
  printf("Thursday");
else if (day % 7 == 5)
  printf("Friday");
else if (day % 7 == 6)
  printf("Saturday");
else
  printf("Sunday");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but can you tell me what connection it has with segmentation error?